# how to make multiple overlapped layout in android(it means make one layout disable and other layout become overlapped)

Tags: android, layout, view

How to make multiple overlapped layout in android( for example I try to make two layout and make one layout to disable and other layout to enable for some operation, this layout overlapped with other layout).

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options:

**FrameLayout**

This allows you to stack views directly on top of each other.  This is nice and simple for some cases, but is limited.  It will not help you align those views, simply stack them.

**RelativeLayout**

This is probably the best option, it allows stacking views on top of each other, but also allows for aligning views with each other.  You can align edge, place views next to each other, or center in the parent.  This is one of the most powerful views in Android.

**AbsoluteLayout**

This is deprecated and its use is discouraged.  That having been said, this gives you pixel perfect view alignment if you know what the exact pixels should be.  The reason it is deprecated is because Android devices have variable screen sizes and pixel densities, so more than likely when using this view you will be limiting your device support greatly.